# What's the difference between using "exports" vs. "this" in Node.js modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Apologies for the slightly half-formed idea, but in getting started with Node.js I am sure I read somewhere that, as modules are objects, `this.myFunc` works equally well for publicly accessible properties as `exports.myFunc` within a module, like so:

**app.js**

```
var test = require('./modtest');
console.log(test.foo());
console.log(test.bar());
```

**modtest.js**

```
this.foo = function() { return "abc" }
exports.bar = function() { return "xyz" }
```

Apart from being "the right thing to do", why should I be using the `exports` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is equal to the `exports` object globally. This means that if a function somewhere in the file is executed with a different context, `this` will stop referring to the `exports` object and instead refer to that new context. This happens in these two examples :

```
// here, this == exports

function foo() {
  console.log(this);
  console.log(exports);
}

foo();          // prints out the same object twice
obj = { foo: foo };
obj.foo();      // prints out 'obj', then the 'exports' object
foo.call(obj);  // prints out 'obj' then 'exports' again
```

This way, it is "safer" to use `exports`, unless you're sure `this` will never be overriden with another context.

Likewise, `exports` could be overriden by a local variable somewhere in your code, but it's easier to avoid this type of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The exports object resolves scope, so don't have to worry about naming problems. With your function you could only have one foo call on this, but with exports essentially you could have as my foo functions as long as they were coming from different exports because those are essentially files that resolve scope.